# Convert vector of integers into a 2D array

Tags: java, matrix, converters

I had a `String` and I was able to convert it into a `Vector<Integer>`.

```
public class VectorConverter {
public static Vector <Integer> v (String s) {
    Vector<Integer> myVec = new Vector();

    //Convert the string to a char array and then just add each char to the vector
    char[] sChars = s.toCharArray();
    int[] sInt= new int [sChars.length];;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        sInt[i]= Character.getNumericValue(sChars[i]);
        myVec.add(sInt[i]);
    }

    return myVec;
}}
```

Now I want to convert it into a 2D `int` array (`int[][]`). For example if I have `[0,1,0,0]`  it will become a column vector, something like this

```
0
1
0
0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Of what dimensions?? The first problem I can see. After how many elements you want row to be changed

Comment: as the example I gave, I want to have an array of size (4,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `Vector` is unadvised unless you use an ancient version of the jre. I suggest you migrate to `List` and base my answer accordingly.
Also, i'm puzzled why you convert to Integer.
You can work directly on the char[] like this.

---

You can try the following for an input like this `[[4,2,6][....]]`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();
ArrayList<Integer> current = null;
for(int i=1; i<chars.length-1; ++i) { // To avoid parsing begining and end of the array
    char c = chars[i];
    if(c == '[')
        table.add(current = new ArrayList<Integer>());
    if(c == ']')
        continue;
    current.add(Character.getNumericValue(c));
}
int[][] result = table.toArray(new int[0][0]); // Maybe this will fail and you'll have to use Integer[][] instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this?

```
int[][] result = new int[myVec.size()][];

for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++) {
   result[i] = myVec.get(i);
}
```